# Что такое профайлинг и метрика в коде?

Tags: javascript

есть такое требования к коду
что это такое? никогда раньше не сталкивался с подобными терминами

Comment: Может быть метрики кода?

Comment: Покуда я понимаю, то профайлинг дает возможность анализировать как код/приложение использует системные ресурсы. В Андроид студии есть такая вкладка отдельная.  Возможно в Вашей среде разработки такое тоже есть. Попробуйте через хелп или поиск поискать этот функционал.